# Is `width` a parameter of the Python object `vim.current.window`?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript-python

I am trying to use PYthon to interface with VIM in my vimrc. I am aware that
this can be done in `vimrc` in VIML, but I don't want to learn VIML too much,
and am already familiar with `Python`.

I looked into some of the examples here: http://vimhelp.appspot.com/if_pyth.txt.html#python-window

Its mentioned here the `width` is a parameter of any `window` object.

However, when I do `py3 print(dir(vim.current.window))`, it gives me the
following output:
`['__dir__', 'buffer', 'col', 'cursor', 'height', 'number', 'options', 'row',
'tabpage', 'v alid', 'vars']`.

This doesn't contain `width` as one of the `attributes` of `current.window`,
however, when I use the following `ex` command:
`:py3 print(vim.current.window.width)`

It does give me a output of `90`, so it seems `width` is indeed an attribute of
`vim.current.window`.

Is this a bug or how this is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I had posted a couple theories as to why width, a valid field in `vim.current.window`, wasn't showing up in the output of `dir()`. The actual reason has been astutely uncovered by **@Mass**...*

Objects are allowed to provide hints to `dir()` by listing the object's fields in an array. `vim.current.window` does so but it's not accurate. It contains...

```
"buffer", "cursor", "height", "vars", "options", "number", "row", "col", "tabpage", "valid"
```

Yeah, those are exactly the fields `dir()` is returning. See https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d79a26219d7161e9211fd144f0e874aa5f6d251e/src/if_py_both.h#L3839

Anyways, regardless of that error, `width` is a valid field and your best bet is to follow the Vim examples that you linked and access the fields like this:

```
:py cw = vim.current.window
:py width = cw.width
```

Or just use `vim.current.window.width` as you've done.

Comment: Ok.. I see.. The `vim` documentation is very space regarding the `variables` contained in any of the `objects`, so I was using the `dir()` command, which basically prints out the contents of that vim-object using the print statement in python .

Comment: @alpha_989 It was worth a try. :) But, like I said, it's hard to say what exactly the exposed Vim/Python objects are. Meanwhile, `dir()` expects things to be purely/strictly Python, I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks no problem.. I guess, I will have to live with that..

Comment: This line is the problem; it could easily be fixed: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d79a26219d7161e9211fd144f0e874aa5f6d251e/src/if_py_both.h#L3839

Comment: @Mass Oh, good catch. I think the main question has been answered ("Is 'width' a parameter...") but I'll mention your discovery in my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks @Mass.. takata mentioned this to me as well..